# insert selected image from gridview to mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I use asp.net, c# and mysql. 
So how can I insert selected image from gridview to mysql table? Please show me some examples.

Comment: What did you try? Show us your attempts..

Answer (score 0):

The inserted images will be displayed in the GridView control.

The GridView has a `OnRowDataBound` event handler assigned which will be used for displaying the Image inserted in MySql database.

## HTML

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1"
                runat="server" />
<asp:Button Text="Upload"
            runat="server"
            OnClick="UploadFile" />
<asp:GridView ID="gvImages"
              runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false"
              OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Id"
                        DataField="FileId" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Name"
                        DataField="FileName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1"
                           runat="server"
                           Height="80"
                           Width="80" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

## C#

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
    using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO Files(FileName, ContentType, Content) VALUES (@FileName, @ContentType, @Content)";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", bytes);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

The Above event handler gets executed when the Upload Button is clicked, it first converts the uploaded image file to BYTE array using BinaryReader class and then saves the Image file as Binary data (BLOB) in the MySql Database.

The name of the file, the content type (MIME type) and the actual file as array of bytes are inserted into the MySql database table.

**Note:** The Content type (MIME type) is very important while downloading the files as it notifies the browser about type of the File.

Comment: There is already my gridview with images. My purpose is I want to insert the image which is selected from my gridview. First I retrieve then I reinsert that image.

Comment: @AbdujalilChuliev: I think you can have a look on [Save and Retrieve BLOB Images from MySql Database in ASP.Net, C#](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-BLOB-Images-from-MySql-Database-in-ASPNet-C-and-VBNet.aspx)